# XCode Version 6.1 (6A1052d) update causes error: 'dictionaryWithCapacity' has been explicitly marked unavailable here (Foundation.NSMutableDictionary)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, swift, nsmutabledictionary

XCode automatically updated and after restarting I found that I have a number of errors.

**Here is the code that is causing the error in question:**

```
    let navBarTextAttributes = NSMutableDictionary.dictionaryWithCapacity(1)
    navBarTextAttributes.setObject(UIColor.whiteColor(), forKey: NSForegroundColorAttributeName)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = navBarTextAttributes
}
```

I'm not sure how to solve this one.

Can anybody give me some insight?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective-C class (factory) methods are now imported to Swift as custom initializers:

```
let navBarTextAttributes = NSMutableDictionary(capacity: 1)
```